# fmt.Print(myError) without implicitly calling Error()?

Tags: go

I want to print everything in my custom error struct like `fmt.Print()` prints any other struct, but since it implements `error` it only prints one field, the one I pass out through `Error()`.

How can I do this?

Comment: please add the code for your error struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type assert the `error` interface to your custom type. Note that you should, ideally, use the 'comma, ok' idiom when doing so otherwise your application will panic if the type assertion fails.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyError struct {
    Status  int
    Message string
}

func (e MyError) Error() string {
    return e.Message
}

func BadThing() error {
    return MyError{404, "Not found"}
}

func main() {
    err := BadThing()
    if err != nil {
        if v, ok := err.(MyError); ok {
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", v.Status) // or v, or v.Message, etc.
        }
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", err) // Fallback. Can wrap in this in an 'else' if needed.
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/TS1FoRd8u3) - and further reading: http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go

Comment: Yeah, but I want to print ALL fields, dynamically, like go does normally. Is there a way? (do I have to use reflect?)

Comment: `fmt.Print(v)` still prints `Error()`

Comment: `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", v)` should print the whole struct. Typo on my part.